# how to do if your browser is failing to read css

Tags: html, css

**i was trying to apply ccs to the the paragraph but it seems like html doesn't recognise the css i don't know why that is happening**

```
 html 

<h1>change color</h1>
<p class="change">I am a developer who is humble and always hungry for success</p>


css class


.change {
color: blue;
font-size :14 px;
}
```

Comment: You should put css inside `<style>  /*CSS HERE*/  </style>` tags

Comment: Or do your css in a seperate file and then include it in your html

Comment: And you should also dont leave space between `14 px`

Answer (score -1):

```html
html 

<h1>change color</h1>
<p class="change">I am a developer who is humble and always hungry for success</p>


<style>
.change {
color: blue;
font-size :14 px;
}
</style>
```